# How to implement two level approval in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm in need of implementing two level approval checks in uat deployment. Once the first level approval is completed it should go to the second level of approval.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the [Manual Validation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Agentless job.

Here is an example:

[image]

You could add two tasks in Agentless job, they  can be treated as a two-level approval to work.

**Note:** You need to add the Agentless job before deployment job.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) with enviroment in your pipeline.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
- stage: Level_1
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Approval 
    environment: Level_1
    strategy:
     runOnce:  
      deploy:
        steps: 
        - script: echo "Approved Level_1"

- stage: Level_2
  dependsOn: Level_1
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Approval 
    environment: Level_2
    strategy:
     runOnce:  
      deploy:
        steps: 
        - script: echo "Approved Level_2"
```

You need to add the two stage for example stage level 1 and stage lavel 2 with your group approvals.

Generate Two Enviroment and add the Approvals.
[image]
[image]